# Create a collection (array) in SASS for use in @for loop

Tags: css, arrays, for-loop, sass

I'm learning **SASS** and I'm trying to pass a collection of data (an **array**) into a `@mixin` and process based on that. The trouble I'm having is defining the **data structure** to pass the values into the `@mixin`

Here's some pseudo code:

```
@mixin roundcorners($collection) {

    $collectionLength = length(collection);

    @for($i from 0 to $collectionLength) {
        border-#{$collection[$i]}-radius: 9px;
    }

}

.mybox {

    @include roundcorners(['top-right','bottom-left']);

}
```

The desired output would be this:

```
.mybox {
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The closest thing SASS has to an array is a list, which you can iterate with the @each directive, like so:

```
@mixin roundcorners($collection: (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left), $radius: 0)
   @each $corner in $collection
     border-#{$corner}-radius: $radius
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive

I've used string interpolation to drop the value of the list entry into the rule itself - I'm not entirely sure that's legal, but I'm not on my dev. machine to check.

I've also used default values on the arguments, which means you can pass in a custom radius. If you do pass in any corner in the list, you'll clear the whole default list (which I think is what you want, but something to be aware of).

A different, simpler way to do this might be:

```
@mixin rounded($topLeft:false, $topRight:false, $bottomRight:false, $bottomRight:false)
  @if $topLeft != false
     border-top-left-radius: $topLeft
  @if $topRight != false
     border-top-right-radius: $topRight
  @if $bottomRight != false
     border-bottom-right-radius: $bottomRight
  @if $topLeft != false
     border-bottom-left-radius: $topLeft
```

By setting defaults, you can call this mixin like:

```
@include rounded(false, 9px, false, 9px)
```

Using 'false' instead of 0 as the default means you don't create more radius rules than you need. It also means you can override and set corners back to 0 radius if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `@each`, I highly prefer that over how I was using `@for`! Your alternative solution seems better suited for what I want to do, but it's good to know about collections as well! I searched and searched and could only find people saying it wasn't possible.

Comment: Thanks mate - I fixed the interpolation syntax as per your note.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved it and allow you to set different radius.

```
@mixin border-radius($radius:5px){
    @if length($radius) != 1 {
        $i:1;
        //covers older modzilla browsers
        @each $position in (topleft, topright, bottomright, bottomright) {
            -moz-border-radius-#{$position}:nth($radius, $i);
            $i:$i+1;
        }
        //Covers webkit browsers
        -webkit-border-radius:nth($radius, 1) nth($radius, 2) nth($radius, 3) nth($radius, 4);
        //Standard CSS3
        border-radius: nth($radius, 1) nth($radius, 2) nth($radius, 3) nth($radius, 4);
    } @else {
        -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
        -moz-border-radius: $radius;
        border-radius: $radius;
    }
}
```

Which means you can set all the radius the same:

```
@include border-radius(5px)
```

or different like this:

```
@include border-radius((5px, 0, 5px, 0))
```

Hopefully keep your generated CSS succinct too :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the code provided by @Beejamin I was able to devise the following solution after fixing some syntax issues.

```
@mixin roundcorners($collection: (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left), $radius: 0) {
    @each $corner in $collection {
        border-#{$corner}-radius: $radius
    }
}

@include roundcorners((top-right, bottom-left), 9px);
```

I however prefer his final solution which allows me to assign different radii to each corner.